# IF Statement I want the value to show as a Percent

Tags: formula-field

I have two fields in Salesforce.  One is a currency and one is a percentage field.  I have a third formula (text) field that I want to show the value of the currency or the percentage based on an IF statement.  When I convert the percentage field to Text I get ".2" vs 20%.  Is there a way to have the value show as 20% vs. ".2"? Below is my If Statement

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Discount_Value_Type__c, "Fixed"), 
    TEXT(Promotion_Discount__c), 
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Discount_Value_Type__c, "Percent"),
        TEXT(Discount_Percentage__c), 
        "0"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You just have to do some more processing to `Discount_Percentage__c`

- multiply it by 100
- then convert it to text
- then append the '%' symbol

you can append two strings in a formula using either `+` or `&`.
e.g.

```
'One String' + ' ' + 'Two String' + ' '  + 'Red String' + ' ' + 'Blue String'
```

Using `&` would probably be better here to avoid confusing it for addition (since you'll be multiplying)

Comment: And that can all happen in the IF formula?

Comment: @KateColson Yes. As long as you end up with the expected result type (e.g. the first argument to the `IF()` must be a boolean, a  true/false), and you respect the types that operators and functions need (e.g. not trying to multiply two dates, not passing a boolean into `DATEVALUE()` which expects a datetime or a string), then you can do pretty much whatever.

Comment: AHHMazing that worked!!! Thank you so much